# Intento hacer selects dinamicos y sale el error jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Con el primer select no tengo problemas y cuando mando mensaje para ver si si toma el clave_carrera, si lo toma, pero no se que pasa con el post.

En el ajax ya mande alertas para ver si la var clave_carrera esta tomando los datos y si los toma, si me muestra que los esta tomando, pero no se que pasa al momento de mandarlos al post.

Aqui esta mi HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>Carrera</h5>
        <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="clave_carrera" name="clave_carrera"  style="font-size: 15px;" >
          <option >Elija una carrera</option>
          <?php
          #En esta consulta obtenemos el nombre de la carrera
            foreach ($carrera as $key) {
                echo '<option value="'.$key->clave_carrera.'"> '.$key->nombre.'</option>';
            }
          ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h5>Plan de estudios</h5>
        <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="plan" name="plan"  style="font-size: 15px;" >
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h5>Materia</h5>
        <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="cbx_materia" name="cbx_materia"  style="font-size: 15px;" >
        </select>
      </div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
          $("#clave_carrera").change(function(){
            var clave_carrera = $("#clave_carrera").val();
             $.ajax({
                //Aqui envia
                type: 'POST',
                data: {clave_carrera : clave_carrera},
                url: "datos/",                      

                //Aqui recibe
                success: function(respuesta){
                  $("#plan").html(respuesta);
                }
              });
          })
        })
      </script>
```

Aqui esta mi datos.php, donde no recibe el post al parecer

```
public function datos(){
if(($_POST['clave_carrera'])){
  echo "<script>alert('Hay post');</script>";
  $clave_carrera = $_POST['clave_carrera'];

  $plan_de_estudios = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM plan_de_estudios 
                                        WHERE clave_carrera = "'.$clave_carrera.'"');
  $html="";
  foreach($plan_de_estudios as $value){
      $html.="<option value='".$value['programa']."'>".$value['especialidad']."</option>";
      echo $html;
  }
}else{
  echo "<script>alert('No hay post ');</script>";
}
```

}

Comment: Te da error porque tu función si no está dentro de una clase no debería de tener la palabra public al principio.

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar que utilizo codeigniter en el backend, ya pude solucionarlo, no llamaba el array de la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un amigo me ha ayudado a solucionarlo, no traje el array de resultado de la consulta de la bd.

Utilizo en el backend codeigniter, por esa razón son funciones public del controller

```
public function datos_plan(){

if($_POST){
  $clave_carrera = $_POST['clave_carrera'];

  $plan_de_estudios = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM plan_de_estudios 
                                        WHERE clave_carrera = "'.$clave_carrera.'"');
    $plan =$plan_de_estudios->result_array();
    $html="<option value=' '>Elija un plan de estudios</option>";
    foreach($plan as $value){
      $html.="<option value='".$value['programa']."'>".$value['especialidad']."</option>";
      //echo $html;
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

}